# Serialization of collections AsReference in ProtoBuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

As it was mentioned in [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347694/protobuf-net-object-graph-serialization-for-lists/7348010#7348010), when a List of objects (member of a bigger object) is marked with the AsReference attribute, its elements are indeed serialized/deserialized as reference. However
the list itself isn't serialized as reference. This behavior breaks the integrity of the object graph. In particular, it is different from  what the MS BinaryFormatter does. I wonder where does this limitation come from and what would it take to have it as an optional feature?

I evaluate migrating a huge ASP.NET app with an SQL state session from the BinaryFormatter to ProtoBuf-net serialization in order to improve performance. The application has a fairly
complicated data model all saved in the Session, so the above seems to be a potential for bugs. By the way, can you recall other significant differences in behavior between the BinaryFormmater and ProtoBuf.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "what would it take" is simply me getting a few minutes to design, implement (twice: runtime vs meta-programming), unit-test (twice: runtime vs MP), regression-test  (twice...), document, deploy, etc. It isn't a *huge* thing

A pragmatic option may be to *encapsulate* the list, so that you don't *directly* need to reference the list - i.e. instead of:

```
objA                 objB
> theList            > theList
```

you might have

```
objA                 objB               listWrapper
> listWrapper        > listWrapper      > theList
```

that is obvious not *vastly* convenient, but it would work *today*. Support for this scenario is on my road-map, though.

Re other significant differences... it depends entirely on what your state model is (and in *either* case I recommend a reasonably simple DTO model here). But things that leap to mind:

- it may be using a different constructor (note: you can *disable* constructor usage in protobuf-net, as an option)
- depending on how you mark the members, you might be working at property level (BinaryFormatter is field level; protobuf-net can *also* work at field-level if desired)
- protobuf-net doesn't have as much support for unexpected types (although DynamicType is an option in some scenarios); *generally* it prefers to know what the data is going to look like in advance
- protobuf-net doesn't serialize delegates/events (BinaryFormatter does)
- reference tracking is explicit (opt-in) in protobuf-net, and implicit (automatic) in BinaryFormatter
- and probably a few other things that would occur if I saw the model

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I'm sure that as full as it possible compatibility with the default MS binary serialization, would
contribute a lot to the popularity of this project.

Comment: @Shay do you mean *binary* compatibility in the output? that won't work... if you mean *functional* compatibility - there are some things that are tricky due to the protocol - in the same way that every serializer (XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, JavascriptSerializer, etc) has subtle differences - this is no different

Comment: I mean functional compatibility as complete as it gets (maybe through configurable options), making the transition easy.